# changing part of src name with jquery, keeps repeating when window resized

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have code written to find the src of all images inside a particular div and change the src name when the window is less than 900 wide. It works fine upon page refresh, but when I resize the window it continuously runs the code and I get this error

> GET
>   file://macintosh%20hd/Users/jessicamele/Desktop/tom%20mendicino/images/boys3_small_small_small_small.jpg
>   net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

It just keeps adding the "_small" over and over again. Here is my code:

```
<div class="threePicsBoys group">
   <img src="images/boys3.jpg" alt="street signs" class="boysPics1">
   <img src="images/boys2.jpg" alt="city house" class="boysPics2">
   <img src="images/boys1.jpg" alt="2 boys" class="boysPics1">
   <img src="images/boys4.jpg" alt="philly signs" class="boysPics2">
   <img src="images/boys5.jpg" alt="religious statue" class="boysPics1">
</div>

$(function() {
    if (windowWidth <= 900) {
        var img = $(".threePicsBoys.group").find("img").map(function() { 
            var src = $(this).attr("src");
            var newName = src.replace(".jpg","_small.jpg"); 
            $(this).attr("src",newName);
        });
    }
});
}
```

I could really use some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script will check if the window is so thin that it has to change the src, but will also revert the changes when it have become wider than 900.
I slightly changed the mechanics to make it work. `windowWidth`, for example, wasn't a declared variable, and the rest didn't seem to do that much either.

```
var thinWindow = false;
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 900){
        if(!thinWindow){
            $('.threePicsBoys.group img').each(function(){
                var src = $(this).attr("src");
                var newSrc = src.replace(".jpg","_small.jpg");
                $(this).attr("src", newSrc);
            })
            thinWindow = true
        }
    }else{
        if(thinWindow){
            $('.threePicsBoys.group img').each(function(){
                var src = $(this).attr("src");
                var newSrc = src.replace("_small.jpg",".jpg");
                $(this).attr("src", newSrc);
            })
            thinWindow = false
        }
    }
})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome, this works perfectly. I was driving myself crazy trying to come up with a solution as I am not the most javascript savvy person, but I'm trying to learn, it can be frustrating sometimes. Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

This code will loop forever when window is less than 900 width. If you wish to you only run on window change width you must add the correct event binding

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    if (windowWidth <= 900)
    {
        var img = $(".threePicsBoys.group").find("img")
        var src = img.attr("src");
        if (!(src.indexOf("_small.jpg") > -1))
        {
            var newName = src.replace(".jpg","_small.jpg");
            img.attr("src",newName); 
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Errr... Doesn't this also keep on pasting _small every time she resizes the window and its width is <= 900?

Comment: I apologize, you are correct! The code has been changed to correctly check if the src contains `_small.jpg` now.